# How to represent successful, failed login and logout events

Tags: usability, audit-trail

We have an audit requirement where we need to track user activity (e.g. successful login, logout actions and failed logins). We have defined 3 event types to track this information.

What would be a nice way to show these violations (e.g. failed logins) or normal events (e.g. successful login, logout events) for the system administrator. Should they be represented as images or just with useful information.

Comment: With a report.  Images are not needed, but proper sorting and filtering would be nice.

Comment: Have you asked the administrators what they want to be able to do with the information? E.g. if they want to use the data for further processing an image may look nice, but prevent them from further usage. On the other hand, an image can be passed around easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Harvey wrote, a report is pretty good. Also, having ratios, such as that of failed logins to successful ones would be a nice statistic, for any particular user, and as an average. You can avoid images, and perhaps colour-code certain numbers once they get to a dangerous level (80% ratio of failed logins to good ones would be red, for example, indicating to the admin that there's something potentially wrong with the login form).

Answer (score 1):

More important than knowing when your users log in is who's logging in as your users and what they're doing in your system.

Comment: I agree, but not sure how to track page views over here. We are just capturing the basic information for the time being